# ASP.NET MVC web.config - Login failed for user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, configuration, web-config

I'm deploying an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm having difficulty with the web.config. The application will be deployed to our server, but will be accessing a database on a different, off-site server. I'm getting the following error when trying to load a page that accesses the database:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> Login failed for user 'LOCALSERVERNAME$'. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'LOCALSERVERNAME$'.

The connection strings in web.config look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="AppEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=EXTERNALSERVERNAME;Password=****;User ID=****;Initial Catalog=AppData;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So the error is for authentication the local server, which is just hosting the files. Plain ASP pages within the application which don't interact with the database are being served properly. The problem only seems to appear when trying to access the database, which is on a completely different server. I also know the connection string for the off-site server to be correct, it works in other applications.

I rarely handle config stuff, and I work in an extremely restricted environment, so this has been difficult to troubleshoot. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is LOCALSERVERNAME the same as EXTERNALSERVERNAME?

Comment: @Anthony No, they're different servers. LOCALSERVER is our local server that's hosting the application, EXTERNALSERVER is somewhere else, and hosts the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually means that the server accessing the database resides on another machine that does not have permissions to the database it is trying to access. More information can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/05/03/understanding-the-error-message-login-failed-for-user-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection.aspx)

Comment: NOTE: All you really need to do is add LOCALSERVERNAME$ to your MS SQL security access and give it restrictive permissions to access the database your trying to connect too. However think hard about this since you can open potentially dangerous security holes into your network from your site.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. We're just going to deploy everything to the same server now. Thank you!